# Slow download WAN -> pfSense -> PC

Tags: pfsense, iperf

i have observed a strange effect in my home network. While i get full gigabit speed between all the components in the LAN and full speed to/from the WAN at the router and the NAS, the PC only reaches roughly 400 MBit when downloading from WAN. All measurements were done with iperf3 and QoS/Traffic-Shaping disabled at the router. Who can explain this?

```
      MODEM (WAN)
          |
       ROUTER
          | 192.168.1.*
 NAS---SWITCH---PC

LAN: Gigabit
WAN: 500 down, 50 up
NAS: Synology 218j
PC: I5@3.6Ghz, Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller, Windows 10
ROUTER: Celeron j1900@2Ghz, pfSense 2.4.5_1, Intel NIC (igb)

iperf3 (-P 10)

NAS (client) <-> PC (server)
download: 941 MBit (-R)
upload: 942 MBit

NAS (client) <-> ROUTER (server)
download: 931 MBit (-R)
upload: 945 MBit

PC (client) <-> NAS (server)
download: 941 MBit (-R)
upload: 941 MBit

PC (client) <-> ROUTER (server)
download: 937 MBit (-R)
upload: 935 MBit

ROUTER (client) <-> NAS (server)
download: 944 MBit (-R)
upload: 930 MBit

ROUTER (client) <-> PC (server)
download: 936 MBit (-R)
upload: 933 MBit

ROUTER (client) <-> WAN (server)
download: 536 MBit (-R)
upload: 50 MBit

NAS (client) <-> WAN (server)
download: 537 MBit (-R)
upload: 48 MBit

PC (client) <-> WAN (server)
download: 400 MBit (-R)
upload: 49 MBit
```

Update: i managed to boost the download from WAN to PC to the expected ~530 MBit by adding "-w 300000" to the iperf3 command:

```
-w, --window    #[KMG]    set window size / socket buffer size
```

The questions that remain: Why do i only need this setting on a Windows system (NAS runs Linux 3.10, the router some FreeBSD) and why does it only affect the download from WAN and not from LAN (perhaps latency? WAN-iperf-server ~25ms).

Solution: I downloaded a current iperf3 version (3.8.1) here:

https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1234695-iperf-381-windows-build/page/3/

The official iperf3 site only provides Windows builds up to version 3.1.3. With the new version, the download speed in iperf on the Windows PC equals the speed of the Linux and FreeBSD system.

Comment: That would not explain why the NAS can download with full speed and the PC with limited speed only.

Comment: I understand your question now. I deleted my original comment. That is indeed strange. Do you have some type of VPN or proxy on the PC for accessing the internet? Maybe antivirus software that scans internet traffic?